# How to write a function that count each character in a string?

Tags: for-loop, count, char

I am trying to write a function that counts the number of times each character appears in a string `s`. First, I want to use a for loop

```
for i in range(len(s)):
char = s[i]
```

Here, I am stuck. How would I proceed from here? Maybe I need to count how many times `char` appear in the string `s`.

Then, the output should be...

```
count_char("practice")
{'p' : 1, 'r' : 1, 'a' : 1, 'c' : 2, 't' : 1, 'i' : 1, 'e' : 1}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple Code:

```
def count_char(s):
    result = {}
    for i in range(len(s)):
        result[s[i]] = s.count(s[i])
    return result

print(count_char("practice"))
```

List comprehension code:

```
def count_char(s):
    return {s[i]:s.count(s[i]) for i in range(len(s))}

print(count_char("practice"))
```

Result:

```
{'p': 1, 'r': 1, 'a': 1, 'c': 2, 't': 1, 'i': 1, 'e': 1}
```

Comment: How do we print the letters in order, so p first, r, a, and so on?

Comment: Sorry, but can you stick to ```for i in range(len(s))```?